# List of GIS Journals and Publications

Tags: references

Currently I am looking list of reputed (or top 50) GIS Journals and Publications across the world to present/submit GIS paper.

Found few links :

1. [GIS Journals and Other Publications](http://www.ncsu.edu/gisined/text-journal.htm)
2. [GIS Online Publications](http://library.uoregon.edu/map/map_section/listserves_tutorials/map_publications.html)

Any additions  will be great !!!

Comment: This is too broad to be answered in any reasonable way. I wouldn't be surprised if you could scrounge up near 50+ journals specifically focused on GIS, but if you increased the list to journals that include GIS publications (e.g. [*The Professional Geographer*](http://www.aag.org/cs/publications/the_professional_geographer)) it would potentially span to **hundreds** of journals. If you mean publications in terms of individual journal articles, it will be too large to categorize in one place and will be out of date nearly every day.

Comment: @Andy W that's true..let me edit my question

Comment: The UK has http://www.geography.org.uk/getinvolved/writingforthega/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this link, it ranks many journals related to geomatics.

http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1467-9671.2008.01106.x/pdf

Answer (score 4):

If you are still interested, the list of GIS journals that is maintained by the 3D geoinformation group at TU Delft might be of your interest:

https://3d.bk.tudelft.nl/journals/